# How can I nest this if/else as per Ruby?

Tags: ruby, syntax

I want to do this in ruby:

```
something() if conditional else something_else()
```

This doesn't compile, nor anything similar from what I tried. Is it possible to have statements in this format or do I **have** to do this as:

```
if conditional
  something()
else
  something_else()
end
```

Comment: *as per Ruby?* Did you mean ***in*** Ruby?

Comment: As per Ruby 'best practices'. I guess I just hate sating that word so I implied it instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, I know of no way to have both an if and else without putting the condition first. You can do it in one line, though:

```
if conditional then something else something_else end
```

or

```
conditional ? something : something_else
```

Comment: also: `conditional && something || something_else`

Comment: Though it does work, I would recommend against using `&&` for conditionals. It comes from python where they don't have `?:`. Even being used to it, I find it much less readable than the other options.

Answer (score 0):

Because Ruby is awesome and doesn't treat statements differently than expressions, mckeed's 2nd answer works perfectly:

```
conditional ? something : something_else
```

Comment: And so does his first answer.